# Bootstrap 4 - center text with button label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve a very simple goal: I have a line - text aligned to left and a button to right. And I want the text to be vertically aligned to button's label. I tried to play with padding, margins,... but nothing worked. I believe there is a simple and smart solution I am missing.

Plunker demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KwRF2uOmKc3aPFQW9DXn?p=preview

```
<div>
    <span>
        This text should match the "Submit" text
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is based on flexbox, so already has classes for applying those alignment utilities. `d-flex` makes the container a flex container, and `align-items-center` does the vertical alignment. Try something like:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <span>
        This text should match the "Submit" text
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto">Submit</button>
</div>
```